Basic Hydrolysis of Isocyanates
During the Hoffmann Degradation of amide, in the later part of the mechanism, an alkyl isocyanate intermediate is formed which gets hydrolyzed into primary amine. If a simple hydrolysis occurs by addition of $\ce{H2O}$ molecule, then an unstable intermediate, carbamic acid  is formed, which decomposes into the primary amine and $\ce{CO2}$. But I cannot find the mechanism anywhere, for the basic hydrolysis of isocyanates, where $\ce{CO3^2-}$ is formed. If the base $\ce{KOH}$ is used, then $\ce{K2CO3}$ forms.
I can simply form a $\ce{CO2}$ molecule first and then react that with $\ce{KOH}$, but I don't know if that's the real mechanism, and I don't want to simply assume the mechanism and move on.

I think what you don't want to assume sound just fine.

An interesting question might be, how could you experimentally tell if KOH acts on released CO2, only after hydrolysis, or if it participates more actively in the hydrolysis mechanism?

Let's be careful about perspective here. No one knows what the real mechanism is. There are only putative or accepted mechanisms that are consistent with known mechanistic experiments and observations. For some possibilities, we do not have experimental evidence and the best guess might be based on similar situations in other reactions that have been studied. Is this one of those situations? I don't know the answer, but someone here might. Or they might not. If that's not a satisfactory viewpoint, well, that's kind of how things are, and it's OK to move on.

I am only studying in senior high school right now and have no idea about how research in the field of chemistry takes place, but what I believe is that some mechanisms are very probable to be the correct ones, and if they are the most widely accepted ones, then at least an invigilator in an exam will say that I am wrong to follow just any mechanism which sounds fine to me.

@CurtF. I feel that it does make sense to assume that, if there is a strong base like KOH present, that will affect the substrate much more (or before) the water molecule does. There definitely has to be some attacks by the OH- ion of the base, and then H₂O probably fills us the missing places by attaching H+ ions. "Probably", but I am not sure at all...

Do you have reference for base hydrolysis giving $\ce{K2CO3}$?

@MathewMahindaratne The reaction is given under the "Preparation of Primary Amines through the Hofmann and Curtius Rearrangements" in the book, "Solomons' Organic Chemistry". I am not sure how can I share the reaction here, from there.
